# Doing Automated and manual testing in parallel in espresso in Android studio

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

Hi i have written testCases using espresso for  the Android app.
Below is my  code. my requirement is i need to manally Login  to my app  by entering credentials  before i  test  the title bar Text.
So i am going into sleep for  2 min.  when i  enter credentials  and click Login button below error is coming.

```
"D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier: TouchEvent: Touch event stream contains events from multiple sources: previous device id 0, previous source 2, new device id 0, new source 1002 "
```

Please let me know how to achieve this....

```
@Test
public void checkTitleBarText() throws InterruptedException {

    sleep(120000);
    onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(actionOpenDrawer());

    Assert.assertEquals("SomeText", (String) textView.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Why not to login in tests?

Comment: we  need to generate one token  for login.. its dynamic credentials  and another thing its a hybrid app code.. so the page is getting loaded as WebView

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just login with espresso? I'd be much easier...

However, If it's really your requirement, You can always launch tests with debuger attached and put a breakpoint in test code (which is stopping test thread). Login manually then and resume execution.

Comment: we  need to generate one token  for login.. its dynamic credentials  and another thing its a hybrid app code.. so the page is getting loaded as WebView

Comment: loading page as web veiw is not problem. How do you generate credentials?